# Preserving HTML entities in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form in which I want to enter elements that will later be assembled into HTML documents. What I am entering, and what I need to end up with, often includes things such as   é, —, and related elements. The editor went and converted those for me, exactly what I'm trying to avoid! What I typed as examples were the HTML codes for a non-breaking space (ampersand-n-b-s-p-semicolon), the letter e with an acute accent (ampersand-e-a-c-u-t-e-semicolon), and an em-dash (ampersand-m-d-a-s-h-semicolon).

I need to have those strings preserved. I want them saved in the database, which they are once, but when I resubmit the page with 20 or so fields on it, because I've made a change to some other field, then I end up with the code being rendered. But I don't want it rendered, I want it preserved so that the browser will render my final document correctly. After submitting it a second or third time, I invariably end up with garbage where my entities had been.

I've tried mysql_real_escape_string(), htmlentities(), htmlspecialcharacters(), even html_entity_decode(htmlentities()) and nothing works. I end up with various levels of nonsense.

I do not need the system to take an em-dash or an accented character and turn it into the entity, although that wouldn't hurt. I just want it to preserve the codes that I've put in.

How do I do this? (And why is it so much work?)

Van

Here's the form field:

`<textarea name="qih_quote" cols="75" rows="5" wrap="soft"><?php echo $s['qih_quote'];?></textarea>`

Here's the line in the submit script that reads that:

`$qih_quote = $_POST['qih_quote'];`

I've wrapped the $_POST variable in just about everything I can think of as mentioned above. All I want is for the exact string that I put in that textarea to be saved in the table, to be displayed in the textarea when I come back to it, and to be saved to the table again without any modifications at any time.

Comment: Form submission and the database shouldn't do anything special with entities. Use `htmlentities()` when echoing them back to the page to prevent them from being interpreted by the browser. I can't give a real answer, since you haven't posted any code to correct.

Comment: Can you show what you input, and where exactly it gets converted?

Comment: Here's the form field: - okay, that doesn't work because I can't hit <enter> in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to ensure you have the correct collation in the MySQL table you are saving the data in so that the special characters are preserved, such as utf8_general_ci, which should handle unicode.

Then try using htmlspecialchars() when saving the data into the database and htmlspecialchars_decode() when reading the data.

Comment: Relational databases were invented some decades before the World Wide Web. I can assure you that HTML doesn't cause any harm in SQL context.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the issue was in the form textarea and I needed to encode HTML entities there. This is the final solution:

`<textarea name="qih_quote" cols="75" rows="5" wrap="soft"><?php echo htmlspecialchars ($s['qih_quote'], ENT_QUOTES);?></textarea>`

Van

Answer (score 0):

I think anyone with this issue might want to have a look at `html_entity_decode` instead of `htmlspecialchars`. The former renders ALL html entities as strings, whereas the latter only works on a small subset, at least according to the documentation I read.